# Why can't the code show the rear camera as default on mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, getusermedia

```
        var decoder = $("canvas").WebCodeCamJQuery(arg).data().plugin_WebCodeCamJQuery;
        decoder.buildSelectMenu("select");
        navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
                .then(function (devices) {
                    var videoDevices = devices.filter(function (device) {
                        return device.kind === 'videoinput';
                    });
                    var constraints = {
                        video: {
                            deviceId: videoDevices[0].deviceId, 
                            facingMode: 'environment' 
                        }
                    };
                    decoder.init(constraints);
                    decoder.play();
                    $('select').on('change', function () {
                        decoder.stop().play();
                    });
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.error('Tidak dapat mengakses kamera:', err);
                });
```

Why can't the code show the rear camera as default on mobile,facingMode: "environment"doesn't work on mobile

Comment: perhaps `videoDevices[0]` isn't a rear facing camera? Also, the documentation uses `environment|back`

Comment: i've changed videoDevices[1] but that still not work, i've read environment is for back camera, is that wrong ?

Comment: `i've changed videoDevices[1]` ... well, my mobile has 4 cameras ... 0, 1, 2 and 3 ... so, `videoDevices[1]` may be front or rear, as may 0, 2 and 3 ....

Comment: `i've read environment is for back camera` ... I've read different, I've read that you use `environment|back` for back facing camera ... but then, that library hasn't been touched for 5 years, so, it may well be complete garbage!

Comment: so what must i use to make rear cam can be default camera ?

Comment: I have no idea as I have no idea how a 5 year abandoned library works, nor what cameras your device has nor what order they come in over `.enumerateDevices` - have you tried the constraints without a deviceId, only a facingmode?

Comment: `enumerateDevices` is not an old library, that's built in to browsers, not sure where you got the idea that `.enumerateDevices` was at all the issue, or even a library ...  `WebCodeCamJQuery` is 5 years old (which is quite a bit when it comes to working with `mediaDevices`

Comment: ah i see, thank u for discuss